# Populate current column with previous row column c# devexpress

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress, populate, treelist

I have a treelist. Its first column is repositoryitemcombobox. What I want is populate current column of repositoryitemcombobox with previous row column repositoryitemcombobox, when I press double space in current column. On pressing first space popup will be opened. On second space it should populate value.How to achieve this.

Comment: How to close a popup of combo. I gave combo.closepopup(). But its not working

Comment: Its working now except that popup is open. I tried to post the code. But unable to do so. Please help in popup issue.